# How to get length of a part of column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a column `name` in my table with a value `PERIOD@1|COLTAB@0.0.1.0.0.0.0.1.0|VOLIDCOLTAB@*1.1.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1*|UTC@0|IDVOL@1`

I need to count the length from `VOLIDCOLTAB@` to the next `|`, in my simple `PERIOD@1|COLTAB@0.0.1.0.0.0.0.1.0|VOLIDCOLTAB@**1.1.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1**|UTC@0|IDVOL@1`

How can I do this in SQL please?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the relevant delimited section with a regular expression, such as:

```
regexp_substr(name, 'VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+')
```

That matches anything starting `VOLIDCOLTAB@` followed by any number of characters other than your bar delimiter.

You can then get the length of that, and subtract the length of your fixed prefix:

```
select regexp_substr(name, 'VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+') as part,
  length(regexp_substr(name, 'VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+')) as part_length,
  length(regexp_substr(name, 'VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+'))
    - length('VOLIDCOLTAB@') as subpart_length
from your_table;

PART                                          PART_LENGTH SUBPART_LENGTH
--------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------
VOLIDCOLTAB@*1.1.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1*          45             33
```

You can include the previous delimiter if you prefer, but you need to escape that bar symbol in the regex pattern:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '\|VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+') as part,
  length(regexp_substr(name, '\|VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+')) as part_length,
  length(regexp_substr(name, '\|VOLIDCOLTAB@[^|]+'))
    - length('|VOLIDCOLTAB@') as subpart_length
from your_table;

PART                                           PART_LENGTH SUBPART_LENGTH
---------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------
|VOLIDCOLTAB@*1.1.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1*          46             33
```

---

If you don't want to use regular expressions for some reason you can do it with `substr` and `instr` instead, but it makes the code a bit longer and harder to read:

```
select substr(name,
    instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@'),
    instr(substr(name, instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@')), '|', 1, 2) - 1) as part,
  length(substr(name,
    instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@'),
    instr(substr(name, instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@')), '|', 1, 2) - 1)) as part_length,
  length(substr(name,
    instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@'),
    instr(substr(name, instr(name, '|VOLIDCOLTAB@')), '|', 1, 2) - 1))
    - length('|VOLIDCOLTAB@') as subpart_length
from your_table;

PART                                           PART_LENGTH SUBPART_LENGTH
---------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------
|VOLIDCOLTAB@*1.1.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.0.0.1.1.1.0.1*          46             33
```